# TDD problem in ASP.NET MVC3 (with DI)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, tdd, repository-pattern

I am attempting to write some Tests for a small project of mine but they seem to fail (I am starting with 1 test 'Create_Class')

I use the repository pattern and use Constructor Dependency Injection:

```
public KlasController() {

    db = ObjectContextPerHttpRequest.Context;
    KlasRepo = new KlasRepository(db);
    LesRepo = new LesRepository(db);
    OpdrachtRepo = new OpdrachtRepository(db);
}

//dependency injection constructor
public KlasController(IKlasRepository KlasRepo, ILesRepository LesRepo, 
    IOpdrachtRepository OpdrachtRepo) {

    this.KlasRepo = KlasRepo;
    this.LesRepo = LesRepo;
    this.OpdrachtRepo = OpdrachtRepo;
}
```

here is my TestClass with testinitializer (which runs before every test) and the first test

```
[TestClass()]
public class KlasControllerTest
{
    private KlasController Controller;
    private IOpdrachtRepository OpdrachtRepo;

    //Use TestInitialize to run code before running each test
    [TestInitialize()]
    public void MyTestInitialize()
    {
        OpdrachtRepo = new DummyOpdrachtRepository();
        Controller = new KlasController(new DummyKlasRepository(),
            new DummyLesRepository(), OpdrachtRepo);
        Opdracht TestOpdracht = new Opdracht
        {
            OpdrachtID = 1,
            VakID = 1,
            StamNummer = "im1"
        };
        Vak TestVak = new Vak { VakID = 1, VakNaam = "FOOP" };
        TestOpdracht.Vak = TestVak;
        OpdrachtRepo.addOpdracht(TestOpdracht);
    }   

    /// <summary>
    ///A test for Index
    ///</summary>
    [TestMethod()]
    public void CreateKlasDirectsToToonKlassen()
    {
        Klas Klas = new Klas { KlasNaam = "2dNet" };
        RedirectToRouteResult view = Controller.Create(1) as RedirectToRouteResult;
        Assert.IsNotNull(view);                
        Assert.AreEqual("ToonKlassen", view.RouteValues["action"]);

    }
}
```

at the moment I get a nullreferenceException on the view (assert.isNotNull fails)

and here is one of my DummyRepository's:

```
class DummyOpdrachtRepository : IOpdrachtRepository
{
    List<Opdracht> opdrachten; 

    public DummyOpdrachtRepository()
    {
        opdrachten = new List<Opdracht>();
    }

    public void addOpdracht(Opdracht opdracht)
    {
        opdrachten.Add(opdracht);
    }

    public string GetDocentID(int OpdrachtID)
    {
        var opdracht = opdrachten.Where(o => o.OpdrachtID == OpdrachtID).FirstOrDefault();
        return opdracht.StamNummer;
    }

    public Opdracht Find(int id)
    {
        return opdrachten.Where(o => o.OpdrachtID == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Normally I should have written the tests Before writting the code, I know (and I am convinced off TDD, as I have used it successfully in my latest Java-project). but it just doesn't seem to work..

here is the code for KlasController.Create action

```
public ActionResult Create(int id) //id = opdrachtID 
{
    var Opdracht = OpdrachtRepo.Find(id);
    Vak vak;
    if(Opdracht != null)
        vak = Opdracht.Vak;
    else
        throw new NullReferenceException("Deze opdracht werd niet gevonden");
    return View(new CreateKlasModel(id,vak));
}
```

I know this is a lot of code, but I really want to make this work.

Thanks for helping me out in advance :)

Comment: Based on your test method Create-action must return the result of RedirectToRouteResult type. Is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As vladimir77 already says in his comment, the method `public ActionResult Create(int id)` is of type ViewResult, so either you change you method to do a`return RedirectToRoute()` or you change your test to

```
ViewResult view = Controller.Create(1);
Assert.IsNotNull(view);
```

A `ViewResult` can not be cast as a `RedirectToRouteResult`.

Comment: silly me :p Thanks, now the test passes and I've written some more (passing) tests. I should be good now, thanks for the help!